# Packard Bell Laptop overheating and crashing, renewed

Tags: laptop, cooling

OK, as requested, here you have the original question renewed, and as a next post the final solution answered ...

Please, regarding a Packard Bell EasyNote TK-85-GN 15.6" 6-7yrs old laptop, with m/b PEW731 (as also on some Acer's 5742 etc.) and CPU Intel Cel. P4600 original now changed to Core i3-M330, and Windows 10 Home v1803 17134.320. It has nowadays suddenly begun to got overheating and crashing in some 7-5-3-1mins, depending on the actual start temp., after a full cold start, seen sometimes on a CPU Temp. app reaching the 89°C, so the constant limit on the fan thermostat seems to be set to 90°C ... on some other laptops I have been seen even 105°C limit ... So, the problem seems to be somewhere on the m/b or it's components ...
Anyway, is there any further ways to tackle this problem than these now already done by me:

- the fan, cooling routes/elements and cover have been carefully cleaned/vacuumed
- BIOS has been updated to the newest available v1.30 maybe from year 2013
- CPU thermal paste has been carefully renewed, also on the CPU change phase
- the laptop has been kept outside on the balcony several times and now even overnight on -10°C frost

I would still like to check some more maybe helpful tricks. So, for ex., where is the shutdown actual temp. set? Could a new fan clear this problem? etc.
I have in mind still maybe putting the laptop for a while in an reg. oven into some 70°C temp. for a few minutes or so ... Have been successfully sometimes rescuing some m/b with these either colds or heats ... but, of course some have been also dying totally/finally this way, but who cares they otherwise anyway scrap, lol …

Answer (score 0):

For info, finally, already since some 4mos, I got this overheating problem solved!

It was caused by the cooler assembly's copper pipe, due to it's contained cooling gas properties weakening, during some 6-7yrs ...

After replacing the whole assembly by a found exact similar one, the problem was gone, and this Windows 10 Home v1903 laptop is now working all well! Great!

Have a nice day!